# Interletter spacing in plain TeX

Tags: kerning

Is it possible globally to change the interletter spacing in plain TeX?

Answer (score 7):

It's quite easy with `pdftex`; adjust the 100 to suit: the value adds 10% to each character width (but the excess space is trimmed out at line breaks, of course).

```
\input plipsum % mock text

% the font we want to space out
\font\tensc=cmcsc10
\letterspacefont\spacedtensc\tensc 100

\lipsum{2}

{\spacedtensc\lipsum{3}}

{\tensc\lipsum{3}}

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Also with XeTeX with its 'letterspacing' font loading option.

Comment: @morbusg Yes, but that's only for OpenType/TrueType/Graphite fonts, not for native TeX ones.

Comment: Yep, OP doesn't say whether that is the case, so I thought to mention it.

Answer (score 5):

There are some possibilities:

- You can manipulate the font sources (when they are written in METAFONT, there is a parameter `letter_fit` usually set to `0pt#` in the source files like cmr10.mf).
- You can write some advanced macros to parse the stream of letters entering TeX's mouth and add letterspacing, see, e.g., this article: Phil Taylor
  Letterspacing in TEX, TUGboat 14(2), p. 141–145, https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb14-2/tb39taylor-letterspacing.pdf